# How to end a while loop in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I've got a simple routine that never quits

```
 import sys
 infile = sys.argv[1]
 outfile = sys.argv[2]
 count=1
 print 'Input file is ', infile
 print 'Output file is ', outfile
 instream = open(infile,'r')
 while True:
     line=instream.readline()
     if line[0:5]=='<?xml':
     print 'new record', count
     count=count+1
     if line == "eof":
         print 'end'
         break
```

This reads the infield... but never ends.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

`readline()` doesn't return the string `eof` to signify the end of the file; it returns the empty string. (Note `readline` retains the newline that terminates each line, so a blank line would be represented as `'\n'`; so a truly blank line can only mean that *no* data is left.)

You *could* write

```
while True:
    line = instream.readline()
    # ...
    if line == "":
        break
```

but usually you simply treat the file as an iterator:

```
for line in instream:
    if line[0:5] == '<?xml':
        print 'new record', count
        count = count + 1
```